# Improper integral : $\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{x\sin x}{x^2+1}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, closed-form

How to evaluate the following improper integral : $$\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{x\sin x}{x^2+1}\,dx$$
I have tried integration by parts and variable substitution, but it didn't work.

Comment: Wolfram says [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x*sin%28x%29%2F%28x^2%2B1%29dx). Maybe you know those functions and can find a way to get there. Otherwise just know the definite integral is given by Wolfram as $\frac{\pi}{2e}$.

Comment: This is a very difficult one, just as MickG showed !

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/491439). Similar to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283862) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/632530). Linked, by way of differentiation under the integral sign, to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9402), [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272622), [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350302), [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540129), and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/779042).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How would one evaluate $\int\frac{x\sin(x)}{x^2+1}$ over the real line?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/491439/how-would-one-evaluate-int-fracx-sinxx21-over-the-real-line)

Answer (score 9):

Since your integrand is even, this integral is equal to one half of 
$$
\int _{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin x}{x^2+1}dx
$$

This integral is the imaginary part of

$$
\int _{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x \cdot e^{ix}}{x^2+1}dx
$$

This can be solved as the contour integral with contour a half disc of radius $R$ with base on the real axis, letting $R$ go to infinity.  The integral along the arc goes to $0$ ( needs some showing ).  The contour integral is equal to the residue at $x=i$, which is $e^{-1}\pi i$. So  taking half the imaginary part, we get $\frac{\pi}{2e}$.

Comment: I was about to say the same thing. I do wonder though why a person would be doing an integral that requires contours but wouldn't recognize this as one that could/should be done in that way. +1

Answer (score 8):

Using the result from this OP: [Integral evaluation $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cos (ax)}{\pi (1+x^2)}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/272622/146687). We have
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos ax}{1+x^2}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-|a|}
\end{equation}
Thus, our integration is simply
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{x\sin x}{1+x^2}\,dx&=-\lim_{a\to1}\partial_a\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos ax}{1+x^2}\,dx\\
&=-\frac{\pi}{2}\lim_{a\to1}\partial_a\left[e^{-|a|}\right]\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2e}
\end{align}

Comment: I think you miss a "-" in front of $\lim_{a\rightarrow1}$.

Comment: @AlfredChern Thanks again. Edited... (✿◠‿◠)

Answer (score 5):

According to the residue theory,

$$
    \int_0^{+\infty}\frac{1}{s^2+x^2}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi}{2s} ~ , ~
    I(\alpha)=\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{x\sin \alpha x}{1+x^2}\mathrm{d}x
$$

Laplace transform:

\begin{align}
    \mathcal{L}\left[ I(\alpha)\right] &= \int_0^{+\infty}\frac{x}{1+x^2}\cdot \frac{x}{s^2+x^2}\mathrm{d}x \\
    &= \int_0^{+\infty}\frac{x^2+1-1}{1+x^2} \cdot \frac{1}{s^2+x^2} \mathrm{d}x \\
    &= \int_0^{+\infty}\frac{1}{s^2+x^2} \mathrm{d}x - \int_0^{+\infty}\frac{1}{1+x^2} \cdot \frac{1}{s^2+x^2} \mathrm{d}x \\
    &= \int_0^{+\infty}\frac{1}{s^2+x^2} \mathrm{d}x - \frac{1}{s^2-1}\int_0^{+\infty}\left( \frac{1}{1+x^2} - \frac{1}{s^2+x^2} \right) \mathrm{d}x \\
    &= \frac{\pi}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{s+1}
\end{align}

Inverse transform:

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[ I(\alpha)\right] = \frac{\pi}{2}e^{-\alpha} \Longrightarrow I(1)=\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{x\sin x}{1+x^2} \mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi}{2e}$$