# How to prove that $\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin{x}\arctan{\frac{1}{x}}\,\mathrm dx=\frac{\pi }{2} \big(\frac{e-1}e\big)$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I found this nice result.

Prove that

> $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin{x}\arctan\left({\frac{1}{x}}\right)\,\mathrm dx=\frac{\pi }{2} \left(\frac{e-1}e\right)$$

[image]

I tried some methods but I can't evaluate it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is another way to evaluate the integral. Notice that
$$\int_0^1 \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\mathrm dy=\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
We also have
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{{x}\sin{x}}{x^2+{y^2}}\,\mathrm dx=\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-y}$$
Hence
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin{x}\arctan\left({\frac{1}{x}}\right)\,\mathrm dx&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin{x}\int_0^1 \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx\\
&=\int_0^1 \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin{x}}{x^2+y^2}\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^1 e^{-y}\,\mathrm dy\\
&=\bbox[5pt,border:3px #FF69B4 solid]{\color{red}{\large\frac{\pi }{2} \left(\frac{e-1}e\right)}}
\end{align}

Comment: +1 Actually, this solution is the same as that of Integrator's, but with a slightly different presentation.

Comment: @M.N.C.E. Indeed, you're right. Thanks.

Comment: +1. I was thinking again in my answer to changed to a simpler one. However, I found that your answer is the simplest one.

Comment: @Venus, how did you convert the single integral into a double integral? I am interested in this method, but cant find a lead...

Comment: @Amad27 Double integral method is essentially a differentiation under integral sign with the bounds. I learned this method here on MSE. You may find it this technique in [Dirichlet integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_integral#Double_improper_integral_method).

Answer (score 21):

Consider following parametric integral

$$I(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin{x}\arctan\left({\dfrac{\alpha}{x}}\right)\,\mathrm dx$$
We have $I(0)=0$ and $I(1)$ yields required Integral.

Differentiating wrt $\alpha$, we get
[$$I'(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{{x}\sin{x}}{x^2+{\alpha^2}}\,\mathrm dx=\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-\alpha}$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/984074/190645)

$I'(\alpha)$Integrating wrt $\alpha$, we get
$$I(\alpha)=-\frac{ \pi}{2}  e^{-\alpha}+c$$

$$I(0)=-\frac{\pi}{2} +c=0\implies c=\frac\pi2$$
Hence,
$$I(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin{x}\arctan\left({\dfrac{\alpha}{x}}\right)\,\mathrm dx=\frac{ \pi }{2}\Big(1- e^{-\alpha}\Big)$$

$$I(1)=\frac{\pi }{2} \left(1- \frac1e\right)=\frac{\pi }{2} \left(\frac{e-1}e\right)$$

> $$\large \int_{0}^{\infty}\sin{x}\arctan\left({\dfrac{1}{x}}\right)\,\mathrm dx=\frac{\pi }{2} \left(\frac{e-1}e\right)$$

Comment: Poor me I am very late for this one. Nice answer anyway, (+1).

Answer (score 13):

With an integration by parts, we have
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty}\sin{x}\arctan{\dfrac{1}{x}}\,\mathrm dx=\left.-\cos{x}\arctan{\dfrac{1}{x}}\right|_0^{\infty}-\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos\;x}{1+x^2}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi}{2}-\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos\;x}{1+x^2}\mathrm{d}x$$ then we use the standard integral $$\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos\;x}{1+x^2}\mathrm{d}x =\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-1}$$ proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9402/calculating-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-cos-x1x2-mathrmdx-wit) to get the anounced result: $$ \frac{\pi}{2}\left(1-e^{-1}\right).$$

Answer (score 6):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin\pars{x}\arctan\pars{1 \over x}\,\dd x
     ={\pi \over 2}\,{\expo{} - 1 \over \expo{}}:\ {\large ?}}$.

> \begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
> \int_{0}^{\infty}\sin\pars{x}\arctan\pars{1 \over x}\,\dd x}
> =\half\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin\pars{x}\arctan\pars{1 \over x}\,\dd x
> \\[5mm]&=\half\,\Im\ \overbrace{%
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{\ic x}\arctan\pars{1 \over x}\,\dd x}
> ^{\ds{\dsc{\ic x}\ =\ \dsc{t}\ \imp\ \dsc{x}\ =\ \dsc{-\ic t}}}
> =\half\,\Im\int_{-\infty\ic}^{\infty\ic}\expo{t}\arctan\pars{\ic \over t}
> \,\pars{-\ic}\,\dd t
> \\[5mm]&=\half\,\Im\int_{-\infty\ic}^{\infty\ic}\expo{t}
> \,{\rm arctanh}\pars{1 \over t}\,\dd t
> ={1 \over 4}\,\Im\int_{-\infty\ic}^{\infty\ic}
> \expo{t}\ln\pars{t + 1 \over t - 1}\,\dd t
> \\[5mm]&={1 \over 4}\,\Im\int_{-\infty\ic}^{\infty\ic}\expo{t}
> \int_{-1}^{1}{\dd\xi \over t + \xi}
> ={1 \over 4}\,\Im\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-\infty\ic}^{\infty\ic}\expo{t}
> {\dd t \over t + \xi}\,\dd\xi
> \\[5mm]&={1 \over 4}\,\Im\int_{-1}^{1}\pars{-\int_{-\infty}^{0}\expo{t}
> {\dd t \over t + \xi + \ic 0^{+}}-\int_{0}^{-\infty}\expo{t}
> {\dd t \over t + \xi - \ic 0^{+}}}\,\dd\xi
> \\[5mm]&={1 \over 4}\,\Im\int_{-1}^{1}
> \int_{-\infty}^{0}\expo{t}\pars{%
> {1 \over t + \xi - \ic 0^{+}} - {1 \over t + \xi + \ic 0^{+}}}\,\dd t\,\dd\xi
> \\[5mm]&={1 \over 4}\,\Im\int_{-1}^{1}
> \int_{-\infty}^{0}\expo{t}\bracks{2\pi\ic\,\delta\pars{t + \xi}}\,\dd t\,\dd\xi
> ={\pi \over 2}\int_{-1}^{1}\expo{-\xi}\Theta\pars{\xi}\,\dd\xi
> ={\pi \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}\expo{-\xi}\,\dd\xi
> \\[5mm]&={\pi \over 2}\pars{-\expo{-1} + 1}
> =\color{#66f}{\large{\pi \over 2}\,{\expo{} - 1 \over \expo{}}}
> \end{align}