# Seperating single integral into an double integral.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus

Please refer to : [How to prove that $\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin{x}\arctan{\frac{1}{x}}\,\mathrm dx=\frac{\pi }{2} \big(\frac{e-1}e\big)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1068948/how-to-prove-that-int-0-infty-sinx-arctan-frac1x-mathrm-dx-fra/1069065#1069065)

The answer by @Venus.

What is the procedure in converting that single integral, dividing it into parts, and making it a double integral?

And also, how Venus took $\sin(x)$ and brought it inside the first integral, and interchanging the integrals?

What is the criterion?

I am very interested in this.

Any **links** advice or comment is very helpful.

Thanks!