# Improper integral of the form $I=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(ax)}{x^2+b^2}dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals, contour-integration

My teacher showed in class that starting with $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{inx}g(x)dx$ for an even function $g(x)$ we have 
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \cos(nx)g(x)dx=\pi i\sum \operatorname{Res}\left( f(z)\right)$$

and for an odd function $g(x)$:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \sin(nx)g(x)dx=\pi \sum \operatorname{Res} \left(f(z)\right)$$

with $n>0$, $f(z)=e^{inz}g(z)$ and $\lim\limits_{z\to\infty}g(z)=0$

However, when he tried to do an example, by mistake he forgot to add an $x$ in the numerator and left it as 
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(4x)}{x^2+4}dx$$

and added the $x$ later. While

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x\sin(4x)}{x^2+4}dx$$

is not that hard to evaluate, many solutions are found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/984044/improper-integral-int-0-infty-fracx-sin-xx21)

I tried to do the first one when I got home, but the methods that I learned until now were unsuccessful. Can I get some help on how to evaluate $I=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(4x)}{x^2+4}dx$ please?

Comment: I would start with the substitution $u=2x$

Comment: By $Re z f(z_k)$, do you mean the sum of residues of the function $f(z)$, or something else?

Comment: I've edited for more clarity. Residues is usually spelled with an 's'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we set $F(a)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(ax)}{x^2+1}\,dx$ we have
$$ (\mathcal{L} F)(b) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(ax) e^{-ab}}{x^2+1}\,dx \,da =\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x\,dx}{(x^2+b^2)(x^2+1)}=\frac{\log b}{b^2-1}$$
hence $F(a)$ is given by the inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{\log b}{b^2}+\frac{\log b}{b^4}+\frac{\log b}{b^6}+\ldots$, i.e. by
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{a^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\left(H_{2n+1}-\gamma-\log(a)\right) $$
and
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x^2+1}\,dx = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{H_{2n+1}-\gamma}{(2n+1)!} $$
is rather non-elementary (related to the [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral)) but pretty simple to approximate numerically.

Comment: I see, and that series is equal to $\frac{Ei(1)-e^2 Ei(-1)}{2e}$ (according to wolfram-alpha) right?

Comment: @Zacky: agreed. On the other hand I find the series representation a bit more intuitive.

Comment: @Zacky: you may use the integral representation for the harmonic numbers, $$ H_n = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{z^n-1}{z-1}\,dz, $$ then switch $\sum_{n\geq 0}$ and $\int_{0}^{1}$ to recover an integral clearly related to $\text{Ei}$. Or just write $\sin x$ in terms of the complex exponential and apply a partial fraction decomposition to $\frac{1}{x^2+1}=\frac{1}{(x-i)(x+i)}$.

Comment: Thanks, but I better stick with those which are taught in school.

Comment: @Zacky: sometimes the things we teach/learn [bring us pretty far from our starting point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2723455/on-the-asymptotic-behavior-of-the-fourier-coefficients-of-1-r-cos-theta-3-2), but that is not a bad thing, on the contrary, sheer curiosity is the core of mathematical investigation.

Answer (score -1):

Some *hints*: 
What is Fourier transform of $e^{-a|t|}$?

Do you know about connection between reverse Fourier transform of function and the function exact?

What about $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-at} \sin(bt)$?

Another attempt : you may consider $F(a) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(ax)}{x^{2}+4}$. Then find a first derivation with respect to $a$. But you should prove uniform convergence of first integral on $E = [1,\infty)$.

Comment: @Zacky no. You know that $F'(a) = \frac{\pi}{2e^{2a}}$ you can integrate the right part and you will have your $F(a)$ with constant , which easy to find with some substitution.

Comment: @Zacky that was my bad. By the same idea change $\cos(ax)$ by $\sin(ax)$