# Evaluate $\int_0^{\infty} \frac {x\sin^{2n+1}x}{x^2+1}dx$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

This problem will help me to solve the very hard problem

> $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac {x\sin^{2n+1}x}{x^2+1}dx$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Questions like "Here is the task. Solve it for me!" are poorly received on this site. Therefore try to improve your question with an [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2951167/edit). Improving could consist of providing some context concerning your task or by adding what you have tried so far and where did you struggle :)

Comment: Downvoter should be care about good questions. s/he should be expert in integration. Moderators must remind downvoter about him/her votes.

Comment: @Nosrati It's not clear what you are saying. However, one can see that this question is a problem statement and no more, which are generally discouraged. See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for more info.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Some questions are too hard such that questioner may not has any idea about them.

Comment: @Nosrati If you read the link, you'll find there's a lot more you can add to the question other than what they've tried. But leaving a question so blank is in very poor taste...

Answer (score 4):

> **Claim:** For any $n\in\Bbb N$,
>   $$J_n:=\int_0^\infty \frac{x\sin^{2n+1}x}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm dx=\frac {(-1)^n\pi}{(2e)^{2n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2n+1}{k}(-e^2)^k.$$

One may use the [power-reduction formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Power-reduction_formulae)

> For any $n\in \Bbb N$ and $x\in\Bbb R$,
>   $$\sin^{2n+1}x=\frac 1{2^{2n}}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n+k}\binom{2n+1}{k}\sin(2n-2k+1)x.\tag{*}$$

Thus,
$$J_n=\frac {(-1)^n}{2^{2n}}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{k}\binom{2n+1}{k}I_{2n-2k+1},$$
where
$$I_m:=\int_0^\infty \frac{x\sin mx}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm dx=\frac\pi2e^{-m},\tag{**}$$
[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/984074/394456) is the proof of $(**)$.
Therefore the claim follows.

---

We can further "simplify" the expression using [the hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) by considering
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2n+1}{k}x^k=&\sum_{k=0}^{2n+1}\binom{2n+1}{k}x^k-\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n+1}\binom{2n+1}{k}x^k\\
=&(1+x)^{2n+1}-x^{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n+1}{n+k+1}x^k\\
%=&(1+x)^{2n+1}-\binom{2n+1}{n+1}x^{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{(n+2)_k}(-x)^k\\
=&(1+x)^{2n+1}-\binom{2n+1}{n+1}x^{n+1} \,_2F_1(-n,1;n+2;-x).
\end{align*}
We arrive the result

> $$J_n=\frac {(-1)^n\pi}{(2e)^{2n+1}}\left((1-e^2)^{2n+1}-\binom{2n+1}{n+1}(-e^2)^{n+1} \,_2F_1(-n,1;n+2;e^2)\right).$$